# Hide second checkbox when first checkbox is clicked

Tags: jquery

PHP generates a list of checkboxs. What I am trying to do is if the first checkbox in the row is clicked hide the seconds checkbox.

```
<input  name="fix[<?php echo $row_TQ01['RecordID']; ?>]0" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="fix0" value="2" data-on="Fixed" data-off="Fix" />
<input  name="check[<?php echo $row_TQ01['RecordID']; ?>]0" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="0" id="check0" />
```

When run there may be two or more rows of data each row having two checkboxs.

Can this be done using JQuery?

Edit:

Not to sure if the question was clear so I am adding more:

```
<?php do { ?>
<tr>
<td width="13%" class="seqid"><?php echo $row_TQ01['SeqID']; ?></td>
<td colspan="2" align="left" class="audititems"><?php echo $row_TQ01['SeqText']; ?></td>
<td colspan="2">
<input  name="fix[<?php echo $row_TQ01['RecordID']; ?>]0" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="fix0"  value="2" data-on="Fixed" data-off="Fix" />
<input  name="check[<?php echo $row_TQ01['RecordID']; ?>]0" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="0" id="check0" />
</td>
</tr> 
<?php } while ($row_TQ01 = mysql_fetch_assoc($TQ01)); ?>
```

What I am trying to do is when the checkbox name "fix" is clicked, hide the checkbox name "check". Both the checkboxs are in the same column and are dynamic in the number of checkboxs displayed depending on the results of an SQL query.

I hope I have written this clearly and many thanks to scrowler
.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If they are directly next to each other in the code, use `siblings`, otherwise you'll need to use a combination of `parent` or `closest('parenttag')` and `find`:

```
$('.checkbox').click(function(e) {
    $(this).siblings('input[type="checkbox"]').eq(0).toggle();
});
```